# parameter based date range and category - recursive CTE assistance using daterange function

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression, date-range

I want a query to return values for rows that don't exist to help formulate a stats query.. I believe it's easiest to share samplets.. Here is my super small sample date set:

```
category    date        ID
Swimming    2013-02-09  1
Hiking      2013-05-01  2
Archery     2013-07-03  3
Swimming    2013-08-05  4
Swimming    2013-08-22  5
Archery     2013-09-01  6
Swimming    2013-09-18  7
NULL        2013-09-19  8
```

My query as it stands now:

```
DECLARE @startdate DATETIME = '04/01/2013'
DECLARE @enddate DATETIME = '10/31/2013'
DECLARE @activitycategory VARCHAR(40) = 'Swimming'

SELECT category AS 'Activity'
    ,CASE WHEN category is null THEN 'No Category' 
        ELSE category
        END as ActivityCategory
    ,DATEPART(yyyy,date) AS 'Year'
    ,DATEPART(mm,date) AS 'Month'
    ,COUNT(ID) AS 'Total Activities'
FROM classes
WHERE date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
AND category IN (@activitycategory)
GROUP BY category
,DATEPART(yyyy,date)
,DATEPART(mm,date)
ORDER BY category
,DATEPART(yyyy,date)
,DATEPART(mm,date)
```

My query currently yields the following results:

```
Activity    ActivityCategory    Year    Month   Total Activities
Swimming    Swimming            2013    8       2
Swimming    Swimming            2013    9       1
```

**I want the following results:**

```
Activity    ActivityCategory    Year    Month   Total Activities
Swimming    Swimming            2013    4       0
Swimming    Swimming            2013    5       0
Swimming    Swimming            2013    6       0
Swimming    Swimming            2013    7       0
Swimming    Swimming            2013    8       2
Swimming    Swimming            2013    9       1
Swimming    Swimming            2013    10      0
```

I've done much research and it appears I need to use a recursive CTE.. I found a "daterange" function that I believe is obviously necessary (outside of having a calendar table).. I just can't figure out how to write the final query.. As you'll notice my query needs to be parameter capable.. (ultimately this will be an SSRS report).. and whatever the user picks, the counts that have no rows return will produce a "0" for the 'Total Activities' if they don't exist in the parameter chosen date range..  Any help appreciated.. here is the function I found:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DateRange]
(     
      @Increment              CHAR(1),
      @StartDate              DATETIME,
      @EndDate                DATETIME
)
RETURNS  
@SelectedRange    TABLE 
(IndividualDate DATETIME)
AS 
BEGIN
      ;WITH cteRange (DateRange) AS (
            SELECT @StartDate
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 
                  CASE
                        WHEN @Increment = 'd' THEN DATEADD(dd, 1, DateRange)
                        WHEN @Increment = 'w' THEN DATEADD(ww, 1, DateRange)
                        WHEN @Increment = 'm' THEN DATEADD(mm, 1, DateRange)
                  END
            FROM cteRange
            WHERE DateRange <= 
                  CASE
                        WHEN @Increment = 'd' THEN DATEADD(dd, -1, @EndDate)
                        WHEN @Increment = 'w' THEN DATEADD(ww, -1, @EndDate)
                        WHEN @Increment = 'm' THEN DATEADD(mm, -1, @EndDate)
                  END)

      INSERT INTO @SelectedRange (IndividualDate)
      SELECT DateRange
      FROM cteRange
      OPTION (MAXRECURSION 3660);
      RETURN
END
GO
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you think you need a recursive CTE? (In my testing, a recursive CTE was the worst possible solution to this problem.) What is wrong with a calendar table? Or even a months table? Finally, [please stop using lazy shorthand for date parts](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations) and [be very careful with regional date formats](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries).

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Links were really helpful to do better coding ty.

Answer (score 1):

Im going to assume that regardless of what the user enters, you will want to look at whole months

Because I still want a valid date and Im going to be ignoring the day anyway Im going to use the 1st because every month has a 1st of the month.

Obviously, if you decide to go with the table of dates instead, you can just substitute that for the recursive CTE (r_cte)

in your script attempt you use IN (@category) for your filter expression, 
I have just used = because we are not comparing our column value to a list of possible values

```
declare @data table (category varchar(10),activity_date datetime, ID int)
insert into @data values ('Swimming','2013-02-09',1)
insert into @data values ('Hiking','2013-05-01',2)
insert into @data values ('Archery','2013-07-03',3)
insert into @data values ('Swimming','2013-08-05',4)
insert into @data values ('Swimming','2013-08-22',5)
insert into @data values ('Archery','2013-09-01',6)
insert into @data values ('Swimming','2013-09-18',7)
insert into @data values (NULL,'2013-09-19',8)

declare @date_start datetime = '20130414'
declare @date_end datetime = '20131031'
declare @activity_category varchar(10) = 'Swimming'

set @date_start = dateadd(day,-(datepart(day,@date_start)-1),@date_start)
set @date_end = dateadd(day,-(datepart(day,@date_end)-1),@date_end)

;with r_cte
as (select @date_start as activity_period
    union all
    select dateadd(month, 1, activity_period)
    from r_cte
    where activity_period < @date_end
    )
select 
    isnull(category,@activity_category) as Activity ,
    isnull(category,@activity_category) as ActivityCategory,
    DATEPART(MONTH,activity_period) as ActivityMonth,
    DATEPART(YEAR,activity_period) as ActivityYear,
    datename(month,activity_period) + ' ' + convert(varchar(4),datepart(year,activity_period)) as ActivityPeriod,
    count(category) as TotalActivities
from r_cte r
    left join 
            (select 
                dateadd(day,-(datepart(day,activity_date)-1),activity_date) as compare_date,
                isnull(category,'No Category') as category
            from @data
            where category = @activity_category) d
        on d.compare_date = r.activity_period
group by category, activity_period
order by r.activity_period
```